# Replace String Array index value with another value

Tags: java

I have a file of comma delimited values that I've read into my program and placed each column (only two columns) values in its own respective String array. One of the columns has three values that are invalid (on purpose) and I want to replace those specific array index values with something like "invalid entry".

The code below prints both columns and the entries that are invalid in the format that I've set; however, for the values that are invalid, the program just prints the value. I tried to make the program replace the value with "invalid entry" but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
public static String[] setWeightPercentageToOunce() {
    List<String> listStringBuffer = new ArrayList<>(ouncesArray.length);
    String[] stringBuffer = new String[0];
    String[] stringReplaceBuffer = new String[0];
    String str;
    String str1;
    double moduloChecker;
    for (int i=0;i<ouncesArray.length;i++){
        double stringToDouble = Double.parseDouble(ouncesArray[i]);
        moduloChecker = stringToDouble % 625; // checks to verify the value is divisible by 625 with no remainder
        if (moduloChecker != 0) { // if there's a remainder, the value is invalid and should be replaced with "Invalid Entry".
            str = Double.toString(stringToDouble);
            listStringBuffer.add(str);
            stringBuffer = listStringBuffer.toArray(new String[0]);
            stringBuffer[i] = stringBuffer[i].replace(stringBuffer[i],"Invalid Entry!");
        } else {
            double conversion = stringToDouble / 625; // converts weight percentage to ounce and stores in double variable
            str = Double.toString(conversion);
            listStringBuffer.add(str);
        }
            stringBuffer = listStringBuffer.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
    return stringBuffer;
}
```

The current output is:

```
Lb 233 Oz 12.0
Lb 23 Oz 8.0
Lb 56 Oz 5.0
Lb 79 Oz 1.0
Lb 45 Oz 13.0
Lb 76 Oz 6.0
Lb 76 Oz 10.0
Lb 15 Oz 7.0
Lb 56 Oz 6.0
Lb 345 Oz 1230.0
Lb 34 Oz 7.0
Lb 654 Oz 11.0
Lb 8 Oz 25.0
Lb 5 Oz 5.0
Lb 987 Oz 4.0
Lb 56 Oz 13.0
Lb 24 Oz 4.0
Lb 92 Oz 0.0
Lb 35 Oz 5.0
Lb 32 Oz 1.0
Lb 35 Oz 5900.0
```

The output should be:

```
Lb 233 Oz 12.0
Lb 23 Oz 8.0
Lb 56 Oz 5.0
Lb 79 Oz 1.0
Lb 45 Oz 13.0
Lb 76 Oz 6.0
Lb 76 Oz 10.0
Lb 15 Oz 7.0
Lb 56 Oz 6.0
Lb 345 Oz Invalid Entry
Lb 34 Oz 7.0
Lb 654 Oz 11.0
Lb 8 Oz Invalid Entry
Lb 5 Oz 5.0
Lb 987 Oz 4.0
Lb 56 Oz 13.0
Lb 24 Oz 4.0
Lb 92 Oz 0.0
Lb 35 Oz 5.0
Lb 32 Oz 1.0
Lb 35 Oz Invalid Entry
```

Comment: Put a print after ```if (moduloChecker != 0) {``` to check if the invalid occurrences are noticed.

Comment: Please add some example rows of the input file/list to reproduce the error in an easier way.

Comment: You can simplify `stringBuffer[i] = stringBuffer[i].replace(stringBuffer[i],"Invalid Entry!");`. It's just: `stringBuffer[i] = "Invalid Entry!";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, Justin, but I think the code you have pasted has a few issues and redundancies. So, based on your requirement, I have reduced the code to this. Please check if this works. Basically, these are the changes:

1. For ease of understanding, I have declared `listStringBuffer`an array instead a list. If a list is necessary, then you will have to replace that with a list.
2. I have assumed that `setWeightPercentageToOunce()` returns an array of converted values for every ounce entry in the original ounces array.

Code below:

```
public static String[] setWeightPercentageToOunce() {
    String[] listStringBuffer = new String[ ouncesArray.length ];
    double moduloChecker;
    for (int i=0;i<ouncesArray.length;i++){
        double stringToDouble = Double.parseDouble(ouncesArray[i]);
        moduloChecker = stringToDouble % 625; // checks to verify the value is divisible by 625 with no remainder
        if (moduloChecker != 0) { // if there's a remainder, the value is invalid and should be replaced with "Invalid Entry".
            listStringBuffer[i] = "Invalid Entry!";
        } else {
            double conversion = stringToDouble / 625; // converts weight percentage to ounce and stores in double variable
            String str = Double.toString(conversion);
            listStringBuffer[i] = str;
        }
    }
    return listStringBuffer;
}
```